# What does the 1.-5. notation mean at the top right corner?

Tags: notation, sheet-music

What is the 1.-5. notation in the top right corner telling me to do? [image: Sheet music]

Comment: FYI: these are also called "Volta brackets"

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled, why there are 6 repetitions specified, but apparently only 3 verses.

Comment: @guidot: Since the 6th repetition has no lyrics, my guess would be that it is either 3 verses with lyrics and 3 instrumental verses, or alternating. The notation could definitely be improved, the score seems to imply familiarity with the song already (in which case, why specify the number of repetitions at all).

Comment: There's only so much room for lyrics within the staff. Very often, any additional verses will be printed elsewhere on the page. I see this in hymnals all the time.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The first part is played six times. The first five times you play the three bars under the bracket marked 1.-5., and the sixth time the bars under the bracket marked 6.

These are called ["volta brackets"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeat_sign) but people mostly refer to these as the "first ending", "second ending" etc. (alternatively "first-time bar" etc.)